# Ubuntu does not start after suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hp

My device is HP-aero, using the ubuntu TLS 20.04 version on this. After suspend, operation ubuntu does not start unless I do a hard reset and restart. I guess it's because of drivers. So how can I solve this?

RAM:16GB & Swap Memory: 10GB

Comment: How much RAM and swap do you have? `free` will tell you. Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use Add comment.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what version of Ubuntu you have. "TLS 20.4" isn't a Ubuntu version. Did you mean "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"? Thanks!